# If a very dense subspace has the discrete topology, is the whole space discrete?

Tags: general-topology

As the title suggests, I have a situation where a very dense subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ has the discrete topology. I wonder if $X$ also has the discrete topology. Otherwise, are there examples of (very) dense discrete subsets of non-discrete spaces?

Recall that a very dense subset is one that meets every nonempty locally closed subset of $X$.

Comment: Add a point to any topology space by adding it to every open set. The point is dense, and has the discrete topology.

Comment: Do you want every dense subset?

Comment: Dear @Exodd, my question concerns *very* dense subspaces.

Comment: @LostinSpace I did not understand your question

Comment: you put 'very' between parentheses, so you wanted both examples. I gave you one

Comment: Anyway, take 2 points with the trivial non-discrete topology. One point is very dense and discrete

Answer (score 0):

For any set $S$ with more than 1 point, the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, S\}$ is non-discrete, and the only locally closed set is $S$, so any point is very dense, and 1 point has necessarily the discrete topology.

Another example is the integers with two zeros.

In general, if you have an atom of more than 1 point in a discrete topology, you have another example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although I was hoping the answer would turn out to be yes :)